# DBNull error using combobox with entity framework

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, combobox, dbnull

In a windows forms application using Entity Framework, I am struggling a bit with a combobox.

I have an entity `Equipment`, which has a * to 0,1 relation to another entity `Person`.
Meaning, `Equipment` can have 0 or 1 `Person` attached.

On the form to Create/Edit `Equipment`, I have a combobox to select `Person`. I populate the combobox like this:

```
 personComboBox.DataSource = context.People.ToList();
 personComboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
 personComboBox.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItem", equipmentBindingSource, "Person");
```

Everything is working fine, if I select a `Person`, but if I leave it blank, I get the following error:

> Object of type 'System.DBNull' cannot be converted to type 'EMDataModel.Person'.

If I remove the combobox from the form, I am able to create a new `Equipment`, inserting null as expected in `Person` field. This tells me, that the model and database is configured correctly.

What I have found so far, is that for some reason the combobox returns `DBNull` when nothing is selected, and the entity framework only accepts null values. So how do I change this ?

I've been pulling my hair on this for weeks, and hope that someone is able to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249041/object-binding-to-winforms-combobox-fails-when-selecteditem-is-null

Comment: Sorry about duplicate question. I was unable to find that on previous searches.
Solved the issue of inserting null by setting DataSourceNullValue to null.
However, I still have problems on setting the field to null, after a previous value has been saved to the db.
Poster on your linked question, has same issue, but no solution.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I have not used Entity Framework except minor playing around when it first came out.